# How to send SMS with VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

So I've been trying to send sms's with my VB.NET application but I had no luck.
I add the carrier and nothing.

```
#Region "Methods"

 Private Sub frmMain_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
' set up the carriers list - this is a fair list,
' you may wish to research the topic and add others,
' it took a while to generate this list...
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@itelemigcelular.com.br")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@message.alltel.com")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@message.pioneerenidcellular.com")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@messaging.cellone-sf.com")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@messaging.centurytel.net")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@messaging.sprintpcs.com")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@mobile.att.net")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@mobile.cell1se.com")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@mobile.celloneusa.com")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@mobile.dobson.net")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@mobile.mycingular.com")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@mobile.mycingular.net")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@mobile.surewest.com")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@msg.acsalaska.com")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@msg.clearnet.com")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@msg.mactel.com")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@msg.myvzw.com")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@msg.telus.com")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@mycellular.com")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@mycingular.com")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@mycingular.net")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@mycingular.textmsg.com")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@o2.net.br")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@ondefor.com")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@pcs.rogers.com")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@personal-net.com.ar")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@personal.net.py")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@portafree.com")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@qwest.com")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@qwestmp.com")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@sbcemail.com")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@sms.bluecell.com")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@sms.cwjamaica.com")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@sms.edgewireless.com")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@sms.hickorytech.com")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@sms.net.nz")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@sms.pscel.com")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@smsc.vzpacifica.net")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@speedmemo.com")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@suncom1.com")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@sungram.com")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@telesurf.com.py")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@teletexto.rcp.net.pe")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@text.houstoncellular.net")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@text.telus.com")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@timnet.com")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@timnet.com.br")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@tms.suncom.com")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@tmomail.net")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@tsttmobile.co.tt")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@txt.bellmobility.ca")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@typetalk.ruralcellular.com")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@unistar.unifon.com.ar")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@uscc.textmsg.com")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@voicestream.net")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@vtext.com")
cboCarrier.Items.Add("@wireless.bellsouth.com")

End Sub

Private Sub btnSend_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSend.Click

' Collect user input from the form and stow content into
' the objects member variables
mTo = Trim(txtPhoneNumber.Text) & _
    Trim(cboCarrier.SelectedItem.ToString())
mFrom = Trim(txtSender.Text)
mSubject = Trim(txtSubject.Text)
mMailServer = Trim(txtMailServer.Text)
mMsg = Trim(txtMessage.Text)

' Within a try catch, format and send the message to
' the recipient. Catch and handle any errors.
    Try
    Dim message As New MailMessage(mFrom, mTo, mSubject, mMsg)
    Dim mySmtpClient As New SmtpClient(mMailServer)
    mySmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = True
    mySmtpClient.Send(message)

    MessageBox.Show("The mail message has been sent to " & _
                    message.To.ToString(), "Mail", _
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
                    MessageBoxIcon.Information)

Catch ex As FormatException

    MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace, ex.Message, _
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
                    MessageBoxIcon.Error)

Catch ex As SmtpException

    MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace, ex.Message, _
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
                    MessageBoxIcon.Error)

Catch ex As Exception

    MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace, ex.Message, _
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
                    MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End Try
End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click

' Upon user’s request, close the application
    Application.Exit()

End Sub
#End Region
```

Comment: Are you trying to send SMS or email?

Comment: It appears that he's trying to leverage the ability to send an email to a carrier's email-to-sms gateway. This is a commonly used method of sending data as an SMS without having to pay for it.

Comment: Daniel, do you get any error messages? What happens after you click btnSend? Does it catch an exception, or just simply not do anything?

Comment: @Doub Robinson, he does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to SMS-enable a VB.NET application, I'd use this third party product:

[Esendex](https://www.esendex.com.au/)

I used this in such a solution. The .NET SDK is devastatingly simple to understand and execute. The rates are reasonable and the support is excellent too.

Comment: Answers involving recommendations is off topic, how does this answer address the OP issue above, it doesn't.